# React _services_persons__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_3__.default.getAll(...)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

I have the following module:

```
import axios from 'axios'
const url = 'http://localhost:3001/persons'

const getAll = () => {
    axios.get(url).then(response => {
        return response.data
    })
}

const create = newPerson => {
    axios.post(url, newPerson).then(response => {
        return response.data
    })
}

const remove = id => {
    axios.delete(`${url}/${id}`).then(response => {
        return response.data
    })
}

export default { getAll, create, remove }
```

That I import with the following line:

```
import personService from './services/persons'
```

And when the variable `personService` is called:

```
useEffect(() => {
    console.log(personService)
    personService.getAll()
        .then(allPersons => {
            setPersons(allPersons)
        })
}, [])
```

I have the following error:

***TypeError: _services_persons__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_3__.default.create(...) is undefined***

Note that the `console.log(personService)` display the following in the console:

```
    {…}
​    create: create()
​      length: 1
​      name: "create"
​​      <prototype>: function ()
    getAll: getAll()
​​      length: 0
​​      name: "getAll"
​​      <prototype>: function ()
​    remove: remove()
​​      length: 1
​​      name: "remove"
​​      <prototype>: function ()
​
```

my react versions are the following:

- "react": "^16.8.6",
- "react-dom": "^16.8.6",
- "react-scripts": "3.0.1"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem came from the functions of my module `personService` that did not return anything. I fixed it by adding a return statement in my functions `getAll`, `create` and `remove` and now they returns a **promise**:

```
import axios from 'axios'
const url = 'http://localhost:3001/persons'

const getAll = () => {
    return axios.get(url).then(response => {
        return response.data
    })
}

const create = newPerson => {
    return axios.post(url, newPerson).then(response => {
        return response.data
    })
}

const remove = id => {
    return axios.delete(`${url}/${id}`).then(response => {
        return response.data
    })
}
```